# Where is, or what happened to, the absent Ocean?

Tags: character, oceans-8

Having just attended a showing of Ocean's Eight, I couldn't help but note the absence of Danny Ocean from the film.

> His sister, Debbie Ocean, visits a crypt, on two occasions, with his name featured prominently. These visits draw our attention pointedly to his character, and his absence from the film.
>  [image]

Is there any information as to why Danny is absent, and what might have happened? I don't recall anything from Ocean's 13 that might explain it, especially given the latter of the dates that were shown.

I half remember Debbie saying, to paraphrase:

> "I hope you're in there," while standing in front of the crypt, but I may have misheard or misremembered.

Which, given Danny's chosen occupation, openly implies a lack of certainty or finality; but is it an open question? Or were there any tidbits that might offer confirmation?

Comment: This is not intended to be a Danny Ocean movie....but it's a good question. The answer is, I suspect, deliberately vague.

Comment: Absolutely, and I feel the movie may have suffered had Danny appeared or been involved (though I did expect a closing cameo, given the olive martini at the end); but given the attention being deliberately drawn to him I can't help but wonder what happened. Or is this part of an extended Ocean's universe of some form, with this movie providing a set up for the next.

Comment: That will depend on how much money it makes and whether Clooney is interested.

Comment: This movie is another film in a litany of women's ensemble films as of late, a la Bridesmaids and Ghostbusters.  Clooney's starpower would have occluded that sensibility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ending, and Danny's state, are deliberately left vague.  Clooney has said that without Bernie Mac he couldn't see the Ocean's franchise continuing.  Matt Damon filmed some cameo scenes, but they weren't used.  There's no mention of why Danny has a mausoleum in the movie, but it makes the connection between Danny and Debbie and presumably it leaves the door open for Danny to make an appearance in a later film if circumstances present themselves.  If that were the case, I'm sure they would include some plot narrative where he would have faked his own death.

Comment: Also it may have to do something with Willie Bank. remember Bullock and Blanchett's chatracters having a conversation about robbing a bank and how the word banks have a serious relationship with their lives in recent past

Comment: Oh..holy god !! the way debbie said .."you would have loved it"..I thought danny is dead !! That's it then..